# What are the chunks of connective tissue on soup bones? (And can I use them?)

Tags: beef, bones

I just finished making a beef broth stew with a big ol' soup bone. I left the random scraps of muscle and stuff attached to the bone while it cooked, and now I've fished out the non-muscle bits. They were white (or pale) and stretchy, and now that they're stewed they're more grey and gloppy.

So, what are they? I assume they're not fat (they would have melted) so they must be... tendons? Ligaments?

Are they edible? Palatable? Useful in some other cooking project?

Edit: Adding an "after" photo.

[image: one of the chunks in question, after cooking]

Comment: We can't know exactly you're asking about without seeing it or without a better description. As a rule, non-muscle "stuff" is full of collagen, so long simmering it adds unctuousness to broth.

Comment: OK, I got off my butt and took a photo. :-) There's not much to see, especially since it's an "after" photo, but there it is.

Comment: Ok, yep, looks like pretty random stuff :) It looks like that little chunk did have some fat, some cartilage and some muscle. That being the case, I would say that my comment is correct and the answer you have accepted is correct. It did some good, but it's not worth anything now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What ever it is, sounds like sinew or other hard tissue, it's done it's purpose now the flavour, sugars, geletine etc is now in your broth and you should probably discard them. I don't imagine they will taste of anything now and the texture is likely to be vile.

By all means taste a bit to see what I mean. It won't make you ill though you may possibly gag...

Comment: Thanks! To the squirrels and birds it goes. (I did end up tasting some -- no flavor beyond the stew itself, and gooey texture.)